# AlarmManager or Service or anything else?

Tags: android, if-statement, service, methods, alarmmanager

Could anybody help me what is the best method if I need to control some things in Android device each 3 seconds, I think I have only 2 methods, these are AlarmManager or Service, but I read that everlasting Service or AlarmManager is deprecated.

So which method should I use?

Comment: If you choose service you must know that only foreground services won't be killed by android when memory is needed. alarmmanager is good if you need to wake the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Timer with an Asynctask. Here is a code for it:

```
    //global variables:
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    final Handler pHandler = new Handler();

 //onCreat:
 TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            pHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // your code

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

    timer.schedule(task, 0, 3000);
```